# Toon Water Effects

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, game-physics, unityscript

I'm working in a game project with cartoon style with Unity3D. There is a beach in this game, and I would like the sea be similar to this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0XrPJP20WY).

I know I can generate waves using the function 
`sin(v.x + time*2*pi)` to the vertices of a plane, but my question is how do I create the effect of waves around the objects on water? also, how it could render the effect of the waves on the shore come and fade?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you may create a particle System which looks like a splashing water. Then Play its animation every 2 or 3 seconds.